# set and display a specific datalist option in a dynamically loaded datalist with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datalist

I have a datalist that is created on the fly based on the user's selection from a `group` select menu.  After the `group` is selected, the datalist is created. The datalist allows users to choose from a "dropdown" list or just start typing in the input box and have the list filtered accordingly.  It is structured like this:

```
<div id="projectSelect">
    <input type="text" name="ProjTitle" id="ProjTitle" placeholder="~ select project ~" list="projectList" autocomplete="off" value=""> 
    <datalist id="projectList">
        <select id="projectOptions">
             <option data-projid="390" value="Project 1">Project 1</option>
             <option data-projid="391" value="Project 2">Project 2</option>
             <option data-projid="392" value="Project 3">Project 3</option>
        </select>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

[image: the datalist control]

In the default use case, the user double-clicks on the input box, a drop down appears, a project is selected (clicked) and the rest of the page (a report) is populated.  This all works great.

In the alternate use case for the page, the `groupid` and a particular `projid` are passed to the page via a stored browser value.

In this case, the presence of the 'groupid' triggers the `group` selector just fine and the datalist element is populated just as if the user had made the `group` choice.  All good so far.

What I'm having difficulty doing is interacting with the datalist via jquery to select the item matching the `projid` that is passed AND displaying the resulting title of the project in the input control.  The title of each project is the "value" of each option.

From lots of other references I've found, the way to select an item in a datalist is to actually set the value of the associated input like this:

```
$('#ProjTitle').val("Project 1");
```

This doesn't work in my case, because the value being passed to the page is the `projid` that is in the data-projid value for each option and not the project title that is the "value" of each option.

One approach I thought of using for this was to select (using jQuery) all of the datalist options and then use $.each() to loop over the items and find the matching projid.  If I could do this, I would then get the valueof that option and pass it to `('#ProjTitle').val()`.

However, when I use jQuery to select the options like this:

```
let $options = $(document).find('option');
```

`$options` is empty.

Are the options for a datalist not accessible with jQuery for some reason? in the Firefox developer tools the options are greyed out as if they are hidden.  If they can not be accessed directly, how can I get the "value" of the option that matches the `projid`?

What other approach could I use to set the selected value of the datalist (based on the `projid`)?

**Edit**
I am suspicious that the dynamic loading of the content is in play here.  The code to set the datalist is inside the `$(function() { })` block of javascript so execution occurs after page load.  Nonetheless, if I add `console.log($('#ProjectList'));` (or '#ProjectSelect') to the javascript I get the following in Firefox Developer Tools:[image]
Normally, I'd be able to access all the nodes for the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comments in the demo are sufficient to explain things, but feel free to ask any questions if you need a more details.

```js
/* Assume this is the id passed to your page: */
const projid = 392

/* 
  Select the option element with a matching data-projid attr 
  and store the actual value for the selected option.
*/
const val = $(`[data-projid="${projid}"]`).val()

/*
  Select the input that is a direct descendant of the 
  #projectSelect element and set the value for it
  to the project name
*/
$('#projectSelect > input').val(val)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="projectSelect">
    <input type="text" name="ProjTitle" id="ProjTitle" placeholder="~ select project ~" list="projectList" autocomplete="off" value=""> 
    <datalist id="projectList">
        <select id="projectOptions">
             <option data-projid="390" value="Project 1">Project 1</option>
             <option data-projid="391" value="Project 2">Project 2</option>
             <option data-projid="392" value="Project 3">Project 3</option>
        </select>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that...the code snippet is exactly what I'm attempting to achieve.  Two things: what is the purpose of the curly braces around projid? I've tried this, and I get "undefined" for `val`.  Does the `const val =` statement need any other selectors to hone in on the options in question?  Otherwise, it looks like I'm running into the same issue: the options seem to be inaccessible.

Comment: The backticks (called template literals) in JavaScript are a way to construct a string. The way you use variables in template literals is with `${your-variable-nam-here}`. So in this demo the value that's stored in the variable I called `projid` gets placed in the string.  Alternatively, you can create the string with `$('[data-projid="' + projid + '"]')`.   You can learn more about template literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: If you share the code for how you get the projid that you said is 'passed to the page via a stored browser value' (localStorage maybe?), I can help you make it work.

Comment: The projid (actually projId) value is loaded by `localStorage.getItem('projId')`.  I verify that the value is present.  I am suspicious that the code for the projectSelect div is not present when the javascript runs.  See my Edit to the original post (because I can't post images in comments).

Comment: you've lead me to the solution.  It was two things: 1) I had to reorganize the code a bit to make sure that the dynamically loaded `#ProjectSelect` html was in place; and then, 2) your code snippet worked beautifully!  For future reference, the fact that Developer Tools shows the `Object { }` as output is a head fake.  Despite it appearing to be empty, your code works as advertised.